# How does AssistedInject for Dagger 2 work?

Tags: android, dagger-2, annotation-processing, annotation-processor, assisted-inject

The [AssitedInject](https://github.com/square/AssistedInject) library from Square is actually an annotation processor that generates [Dagger 2](https://google.github.io/dagger/) modules. Dagger 2 is also an annotation processor.

And as I know there is no way to control the [order of processors execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29193806/specifying-order-of-annotation-processors).

In this [example](https://github.com/square/AssistedInject/blob/master/assisted-inject-sample-android/src/main/java/com/example/MainModule.java) (see snippet below) you can see that the module has dependency on generated by AssistedInject class `AssistedInject_MainModule`. So in case if Dagger 2 will run first the build should fail because of at this moment `AssistedInject_MainModule` does not exist.

But it can be compiled. How does it work?

```
@AssistedModule 
@Module(includes = AssistedInject_MainModule.class) 
public abstract class MainModule { 
    @Provides static @Exclamation String provideExclamation() {
        return "!"; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And as I know there is no way to control the order of processors execution.

I did not look into how either Dagger 2 or AssistedInject work under the hood, but in general Annotation Processing is [done in multiple rounds](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html).

> Annotation processing happens in a sequence of rounds. On each round, a processor may be asked to process a subset of the annotations found on the source and class files produced by a prior round.

Files get generated during those rounds, but validation (and errors) happens on a later or last round, when every file was generated and processed. This is also mentioned on a [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29197680/1837367) on the question you linked. Someone also wrote a detailed answer about [how rounds work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47782562/1837367) on a different question.

Comment: Yeah, thank you for your answer. Looks like multi-round compilation should solve that. I'm trying to implement my own annotation processor similar to AssitedInject and see `Unresolved reference` error. So maybe the reason for my issue is in something else. I'll check it.

Comment: So I've finished my research. Everything in the answer is correct. The key in the `AssistedInject` is that the library generates Java code and uses `Filer` api for file creating. In this case, files from all generators are visible for each other. I've tried to generate Kotlin code in my processor and did not use `Filer`. So in my case dagger really did not see my files during the rounds.